# Can't Upload image using using php

Tags: php

I can not upload image. And i am using lampp server in ubuntu. It shows some errors that i can not figure out..

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
 {
    $fileType = $_FILES["file"]["type"];

    if (($fileType == "image/gif") ||
            ($fileType == "image/jpeg") ||
            ($fileType == "image/jpg") ||
            ($fileType == "image/png")) {
        //Check if file exists
        if (file_exists("Images/Coffee/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo "File already exists";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "Images/Coffee/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Uploaded in " . "Images/Coffee/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    } }
```

And my errors are

Warning: move_uploaded_file(Images/Coffee/costa.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/newphp/uplaodimage.php on line 23

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/phpE2uIod' to 'Images/Coffee/costa.png' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/newphp/uplaodimage.php on line 23
Uploaded in Images/Coffee/costa.png

Comment: its clear in warning message. you need to give write permission in your uploaded path

Comment: How can i do that? Please explain.Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not write permission in your directory where you store file so you  have first give the write permission to your directory where you want to upload your file
Like in Ubuntu:

> chmod -R 777 /path..

Answer (score 0):

```
bool is_writable ( string $filename_or_directory )
```

Will tell you is directory of file is writable